# Meteor Android REST/DDP Connection

Tags: android, node.js, meteor, ddp

I am trying to connect my app to my MeteorJs application. I the app is logged into, its checks the Meteor DB for the user in the DB, or if not create the new user. I would also like the app to subscribe to the meteor collection so when It is updated its send a notification to the Android App which n turn returns a response.

I have already have rest api set up to take data from my arduino board. But there is no subscription.

I have found this package that uses DDP which seems fine.
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP

But when is connects to the Meteor app it says connect to a WEbsocket.

How is the web socket made and work with meteor.

I found this
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Meteor,-WebSocket-and-Long-Polling

but it is written in Java ad I dont see how a collection is attached to some sort of subscription. To me it looks like JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [meteor-rest](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest).

> A set of packages that makes it easy to make your Meteor app's data
>   accessible over HTTP. Easily integrate your Meteor backend into a
>   native mobile app or query your data from your Rails or PHP app.